# Sunspot (Rails) does not honor data_path configuration

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using sunpot_rails gem with the following config in `sunspot.yml`:

```
test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: <%= 8990 + (ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] || '1').to_i %>
    path: /solr/test
    pid_dir: solr/pids/test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
    data_path: solr/test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>/data
```

It is successfully reading different `port` and `pid_dir` when I change the `TEST_ENV_NUMBER` environment variable.
However my problem is that it always points to the same data directory and `data_path` has no effect. Actually an empty directory is created but solr admin shows the same path. See below for `/default/data` being used.

I am aware that a [recent commit](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/commit/2790bda3765f8618cb85169a49c88119a46da228) removed that configuration, but I am using my own branch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question, I will first tell why I need to change the data directory from the sunspot config files, rather than from solr configuration.
I wanted to have multiple instances of Solr to run tests in parallel using the [parallel_tests gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests).

I figured out that only 1 Solr instance is needed. However, parallel tests can be achieved through 1 running instance but with multiple Solr cores.
To do this you need to update `solr/solr.xml` by adding more cores:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
    <core name="default"     instanceDir="." dataDir="default/data"/>
    <core name="development" instanceDir="." dataDir="development/data"/>
    <core name="test"        instanceDir="." dataDir="test/data"/>
    <core name="test2"       instanceDir="." dataDir="test2/data"/>
    <core name="test3"       instanceDir="." dataDir="test3/data"/>
    <core name="test4"       instanceDir="." dataDir="test4/data"/>
    <core name="test5"       instanceDir="." dataDir="test5/data"/>
    <core name="test6"       instanceDir="." dataDir="test6/data"/>
    <core name="test7"       instanceDir="." dataDir="test7/data"/>
    <core name="test8"       instanceDir="." dataDir="test8/data"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

Then restart Solr to create those new cores:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:restart
```

Then modify `config/sunspot.yml` by appending the environment variable to the path:

```
test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: DEBUG
    path: /solr/test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
```

Now whenever you run the parallel tests, the appropriate path/core will be selected:

```
bundle exec rake parallel:spec
```